# Outlook mail automation - error only when Outlook is already running

Tags: vb.net, winforms, email, outlook

I have written a sub to send an e-mail through Outlook when I click a send button located in a WinForm.  If Outlook is closed, my code works fine.  When Outlook is already opened, I keep getting an error with OutMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in OfficeAutomation.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'. 
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA).

```
Private Sub EmailOut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EmailOut.Click
    Dim oApp As Outlook.Application = Nothing

    ' Check whether there is an Outlook process running.
    Dim outlookRunning As Integer = Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Length
    If outlookRunning > 0 Then
        ' If Outlook is running, use the GetActiveObject method to obtain the 
        ' process and cast it to an Application object.
        Try
            oApp = TryCast(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application"),  _
                Outlook.Application)
        Catch generatedExceptionName As System.Exception
            oApp = TryCast(Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application")),  _
                Outlook.Application)
        Finally
            ' Kill Outlook and then restart it as a last resort.
            Dim workers As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK")
            For Each worker As Process In workers
                worker.Kill()
                worker.WaitForExit()
                worker.Dispose()
            Next
        End Try
    Else
        ' If Outlook is not running, create a new instance of Outlook.
        oApp = New Outlook.Application()
        Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Try
            ' try to use default profile and do not open a window
            ' if login fails, then we must pop up a window and let the 
            ' user choose a profile to allow access
            ns.Logon("", "", False, System.Reflection.Missing.Value)
        Catch generatedExceptionName As System.Exception
            ' use default profile and pop up a window
            ns.Logon("", "", True, True)
        End Try
        ns = Nothing
    End If
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem

    OutMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailAdr.Text) Then
            .To = EmailAdr.Text
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter an e-mail address", "Missing Recipient", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(CcAdr.Text) Then
            .CC = CcAdr.Text
        End If
        .Subject = OutSubject.Text
        .Body = OutTextBox.Text
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        .Send()
    End With
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    oApp = Nothing
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.Shell("taskkill /F /IM outlook.exe", Microsoft.VisualBasic.vbHide)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use GetActiveObject - Outlook is a singleton, CreateInstance will return a pointer to the already running instance.

Comment: I tried replacing the If running try line with: oApp = TryCast(Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application")), Outlook.Application) with no luck. The MSDN page on Activator.CreateInstance is vague when dealing with processes. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Do you get the same error? Are both your app and Outlook running in the same security context? Is either app running as an administrator? Is your app running from Windows Explorer or VS debugger?

Comment: I resolved the issue looking into these details.  Ended up reworking my code to make a bit simpler. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should try creating a new instance of outlook regardless of whether it's running or not.  I don't think there's any need to try to grab onto the running instance (if that's even possible, which it seems like is not).

EDIT: I would definitely take Dmitry's word over mine, however.